# Best practice for selecting a recurring event?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, design-patterns, datetimepicker, ease-of-use

I need to allow users to set the frequency with which they would like for a certain task to occur (example- every X days/week/month/year). So far, what I've come up with is an input box and a drop down to select either Days, weeks, months or years as options. [image: Frequency picker]
Could this be confusing and are there any better patterns for such cases?

Comment: Are there any limits, minima & maxima, on what they can set? Also what's the use case for this?

Comment: @DarrylGodden There are no limits as such. It's to automate file scraping from another location. The user gets to define if they'd like to scrape files every x interval of days/months (most common cases) or even years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Planning of tasks tends to be **more contextual than mathematical**. What does that mean? It means that you

- go to soccer practice **every Tuesday**,
- pay your rent on the **last work day of the month**,
- download that report on **every 15th**,
- meet with Jeff on the **first Monday of each month**
- check up on aunt Jeannie at least **once in a quarter**.

In the Gregorian calendar, only the first bullet point is a consistent interval. All other "tasks" depend upon the length of months, placement of calendar weeks, work week definitions, beginning of the week definitions.

What you need to do is to

- Give a natural language context (for your locale)
- Take away complexity in the beginning
- Offer the most popular choices
- Allow customization down the road

Microsoft, e.g., is doing a good job with this in their **Outlook web app**.  (Even if somewhat inconsistent cross-device)

#### 1. Desktop

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### 2. Mobile

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I Think there should be hierarchy in layout and options should be daily, weekly, monthly as per the below example[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Information hierarchy in your case is reversed**

> You will first have to take make the user select desired interval and
>   then allow the user to input number of days/week/months.

We recently designed a similar control in our product. You can use it for inspiration.

[image]

Comment: Arguably, information hierarchy is just as reversed in natural speech (in English, at least; this must not hold true for all languages).

Comment: "Value" seems unclear to me here. Do you want "Every 30 days" or "the 30th day"?

Comment: @TimFitzGerald Yes Value in this case will not be clear. Maybe we can write "Enter number of days/weeks/years" in the input as placeholder

Answer (score 3):

I would say that your approach should depend on the tasks your users need to perform. For example:

- if I want to schedule a meeting which occurs every Monday morning I would want to set a start/end date and frequency
- if I am a doctor and plan therapy for my patient I would probably prefer to choose the number of occurrences and don't bother about the start/end date.
- I may want to use a combination of the above

Explore the user flow and what users need to achieve their goals and you will find the answer.